# How to make user input follow list in specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-input

I have a code block which makes the user input Fibonacci numbers. The code block:

```
    numb_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
    numb = int(input('Enter the next Fibonacci number >'))
    while numb in numb_list and numb <= 50:
      numb = int(input('Enter the next Fibonacci number >'))
        if numb in numb_list:
          print('Well done')
        else:
          print('Try again')
```

I am asking the user to input these numbers. When the user input goes over 50 or enters all the correct numbers the program gives output 'Well done'. If user input makes a mistake the program outputs 'Try again'. This is working perfectly but how will i make the user input follow this list in this specific order and if its not in this order the program outputs 'Try again'.

This is the current output:

```
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >1
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >1
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >2
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >3
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >8
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >3
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >
```

This is the output i would like to achieve:

```
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >1
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >1
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >2
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >3
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >8
    Enter the next Fibonacci number >3
    Try again
```

Unfortunately I am having trouble achieving this output. Will someone be able to help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate the target number through `numb_list` instead and use a `while` loop to keep asking the user for input until the input number matches the target number:

```
numb_list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
for target in numb_list:
    while int(input('Enter the next Fibonacci number >')) != target:
        print('Try again')
print('Well done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to print `Well done` every time a correct value is entered, and that you modify your `numb_list` to have an extra 1 in it (As per the Fibonacci sequence), you can move through the list with an index every time you get the next value in the sequence:

```
numb_list = [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
numb = 0
current_index = 1
while numb <= 50:
    numb = int(input('Enter the next Fibonacci number >'))
    if numb_list[current_index] == numb:
        print('Well done')
        current_index += 1
    else:
        print('Try again')
```

If you dont want to print `Well done` every iteration, you can simply remove the `print()` statement